# IndexOutOfBoundsException after refilling RecyclerView with AsyncTask and notifyItemInserted()

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a RecyclerView that I fill with data using an AsyncTask. When I clear the List with `clear()` and `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` and then try to fill it again with the AsyncTask, I get this exception:

`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter position`

Replacing `notifyItemInserted()` with `notifyDataSetChanged()` inside my AsyncTask solves the problem, but I don't think that's a good solution, and I'd like to understand why the first method doesn't work.

My AsyncTask `doInBackground()` method:

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                mDataContainer.addItem(i);
                publishProgress(i);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

and my AsyncTask `onProgressUpdate()` method:

```
@Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(values[0]);
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
```

I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

---

Edit:
Here is the adapter:

```
private class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
        private List<Item> mItems;
        private int selectedPos = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;

        private class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
            private Item mItem;
            private TextView mNameTextView;
            private TextView mMembersTextView;

            MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
                mNameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
                mMembersTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_members);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                notifyItemChanged(selectedPos);
                selectedPos = getLayoutPosition();
                notifyItemChanged(selectedPos);
                mOnItemSelectedListener.onItemSelected(mItem);
            }
        }

        MyAdapter(List<Item> items) {
            mItems = items;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

            return new MyViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int position) {
            Item item = mItems.get(position);
            myViewHolder.mItem = item;
            myView.mNameTextView.setText(item.getName());
            myView.mMembersTextView.setText(String.format(Locale.US,"%d/50", item.getMembers()));

            if (!mIsInit) {
                // select item that was selected before orientation change
                if (selectedPos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    Item selectedItem = mItems.get(selectedPos);
                    mOnItemSelectedListener.onItemSelected(selectedItem);
                // else select item 0 as default on landscape mode
                } else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
                    selectedPos = 0;
                    mOnItemSelectedListener.onItemSelected(MyViewHolder.mItem);
                }
                mIsInit = true;
            }

            if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                myViewHolder.itemView.setSelected(selectedPos == position);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mItems.size();
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show us the adapter class also @Colin

Comment: I've added it to my question. I hope it's not too much :) @elhoucineayoub

Comment: Please post more of your code, including what mDataContainer is, how you're clearing the list, etc.

Comment: What is 'mDataContainer.addItem(i);' here. mDataContainer is object of which class? How you are making changes in adapter?

Comment: mDataContainer is a singleton with an ArrayList. additem adds an item to the list. I have a method to clear the list and inside that method I just do .clear and notifyDataSetChanged(). Nothing complicated. @pankaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only be adding items to the adapter (and notifying) from the UI thread.  Changing the adapter's backing data from the background and then notifying on the UI thread later via `onProgressUpdate` is quite likely to result in race conditions.  In this case, `mDataContainer.addItem(i);` should be moved to `onProgressUpdate` before you notify the adapter.

It's hard to confirm if that's the only issue without seeing the definition of `mDataContainer`, but fixing the synchronization here would definitely be the first step toward fixing this.

Comment: mDataContainer is a singleton with an ArrayList. additem adds an item to the list.

Comment: I think I understand it now. Download data in doInBackground(), call publishProgress() with the data as argument and then set the UI with the data in onProgressUpdate(). In my simple code the data would just be the integer from the for loop.

Now it works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better if you add all value in background and notify adapter after all data inserted"

```
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                mDataContainer.addItem(i);
            }
            return null;
        }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         mAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, 100);
     }
```

I also suggest you should not use `AsyncTask` because it is [deprecated on Android 11](https://www.xda-developers.com/asynctask-deprecate-android-11/)

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned that it's an assignment from my university. They want me to use an AsyncTask and to update the RecyclerView after each new entry.

Comment: Adding items from a background thread is a bad idea, please don't do this.  This is very likely to result in subtle bugs due to race conditions and CPU caching.  You should only be adding items from the UI thread, and notifying the adapter there..